# Prevent negative numbers in Textview android - Code

Tags: java, android, textview, negative-number

Is it possible to stop getting negative numbers in TextView in android by writing a code in java.

I tried this

```
int up = 0;
TextView textview;

        if (allowNagativeNumbers == false) {
            if ( up < 0 ) 
            {
                up = 0;
                textview.setText(0);
            }
        }
```

but it still allows negative numbers. I am not sure if this code is right but by this code I mean everytime the value for up / text in textview is less then 0 e.g. -1 then change the value of up to 0 and make the textview text 0.

Comment: use a NumberSpinner instead

Comment: I have to use textview

Comment: Basically, in my app there is a button and if that button is pressed the textview will stop doing negative numbers but if that button is not pressed then it will do negative numbers along with positives.

Comment: Impossible to help you without a good code sample illustrating your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Before displaying your number in `TextView` use `Math.abs()` function on your number.This function will give you absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want this to happen in real-time? Are you using a listener for the textview? If so make sure this is inside a listener and also double check and make sure that allowNegativeNumbers is actually false.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own TextView class (you will also be able to use it in XML files).

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    @Override
    public void setText (CharSequence text, BufferType type)
    {
        if(Integer.valueOf(text) > 0)
        {
            super.setText (text, type);
        }
        else
        {
            super.setText ("0", type);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try These statements

```
int up = 5;
up = up >0 ? up: 0;

and set the text in textView.
```

another way

get the text from textView and convert it into string.

```
int up = Integet.parseInt(textView.getText());
up = up >0 ? up: 0;
and set the text in textView.
```